# How to apply a function to a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Write a function which takes a matrix that can be coerces into a matrix; the function should return a matrix which is the same as the function argument, but every even number is not changed and odd number is doubled.

[image]

I'm very new to R. Can someone help me complete my codes:

```
mx = matrix(c(1,1,3,5,2,6,-2,-1,-3), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
fun = function(mx){
  for(i in mx){
    if(i %% 2 == 0){
      return(i)
    }
    else if(i %% 2 > 0){
      return(2*i)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your matrix has *only* positive or negative integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't need a function, just use the built-in function `ifelse`:

```
mx <- ifelse(mx %% 2 == 0, mx, 2*mx)
```

Or, if you prefer to encapsulate it into a function:

```
fun = function(mx) {
  ifelse(mx %% 2 == 0, mx, 2*mx)
}
res <- fun(mx)
##     [,1] [,2] [,3]
##[1,]    2    2    6
##[2,]   10    2    6
##[3,]   -2   -2   -6
```

**Explanation:**

`ifelse` performs a vectorized comparison over all elements of the matrix mx to see if each element is even (i.e., `mx %% 2 == 0`). For each element if this comparison condition is `TRUE`, the next argument is returned, which in this case is just the value from that element in `mx`. Otherwise, the last argument is returned, which is `2` times the value from that element in `mx` as you wish.

Comment: Does mx represent an entry of the matrix here?

Comment: No, `mx` is your matrix. This function (and `ifelse`) is vectorized across all elements of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

That's easy using indices :)

```
double_odd <- function(mx){
  odds_idx <- (mx %% 2 != 0)
  mx[odds_idx] <- 2 * mx[odds_idx]
  mx # If it is the last statement, you don't need return
}
```

Cheers

Comment: i think your codes might have some mistakes, coz i got another result: matrix(C(1,1,3,5,4,12,-4,-1,-3),byrow = TRUE) which is not the answer for the questionn

Comment: Sorry fixed it! I was doubling even numbers ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Using your try:

```
fun = function(mx){
 res <- matrix(data = NA, ncol = ncol(mx), nrow = nrow(mx))
  for(i in 1:ncol(mx)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(mx))
      if(mx[j, i] %% 2 == 0){
        res[j, i] <- mx[j, i] 
      }else{
        res[j, i] <- 2 * mx[j, i] 
      }
  }
 return(res)
}
```

of course not the most elegant solution :)